# How to calculate cumulative amount based on daily percent change in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

original dataframe is:

| date | percent_change |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/12/01 | 2 |
| 2022/12/02 | -1 |
| 2022/12/02 | 3 |

I want to assume initial value as 100. and add a new column which shows cumulative value till date.

expected output:

| date | percent_change | cumulative value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/12/01 | 2 | 102 |
| 2022/12/02 | -1 | 100.98 |
| 2022/12/02 | 3 | 104.0094 |

Comment: Input and output look the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) with divide by `100` and adding `1`, last multiple by `100`:

```
first = 100
df['cumulative value'] = df['percent_change'].div(first).add(1).cumprod().mul(first)
print (df)
            percent_change  cumulative value
date                                        
2022-12-01               2          102.0000
2022-12-02              -1          100.9800
2022-12-02               3          104.0094
```

Comment: Hey @jezrael, Though I am getting the correct result, Just wanted to understand the answer you provided. could you please feed the value of first row in you statement?
something like below:
(2/100)*2/100   (don't understand)

Comment: @shyamyadav - first is `((2/100) + 1) * 100`, next is `((-1/100) + 1) * 1.02 * 100`

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet fulfills intended behavior.

```
import pandas as pd
df_dict = {"percent_change": [2,-1,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
print(df.head())
cum_sum = 100
cum_sum_list = []
for i in df['percent_change']:
    cum_sum = cum_sum + cum_sum * i / 100
    cum_sum_list.append(cum_sum)
df['cumulative'] = cum_sum_list
print(df.head())
```

The output of the code :

```
       percent_change  cumulative
0           2    102.0000
1          -1    100.9800
2           3    104.0094
```